# Unable to print your web pages from Firefox

Tags: bug, firefox, printing

It is almost two days that the print of your web pages (faces of solved problems) is not possible.

The problem is that only the first page, for example [/questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=560&sort=active) comes in "print view window" and the other pages could not be printed ( but this only happens in Firefox).

Why is this and can this be fixed?

(This doesn't happen on Chrome)

Comment: might be handy to give an example of a page that won't print

Comment: I repro-ed this for the /questions page in FF/Win10 cc @JourneymanGeek

Comment: Appears to be a common Firefox issue, where CSS is causing this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1100801

Comment: Lots of sites won't print properly from FF. Considering that, I think it's FF's problem.